# Abrindo PDF em nova aba usando ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, aba

Estou testando o código abaixo, mas não tem nenhuma ação quando clico botão para abrir um PDF em nova aba.

Ta faltando algo abaixo?

Teste.aspx

```
Clique <asp:LinkButton OnClick="linkPDF_click" ID="linkPDF" runat="server">aqui</asp:LinkButton> para abrir seu PDF.
```

Teste.aspx.cs

```
protected void linkPDF_click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/MediaFiles/Comuns/PDF/Arquivo Fatura.pdf");
  WebClient User = new WebClient();
  Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);
  if(FileBuffer != null)
  {
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
  }
}
```

Comment: mas o quê a requisição retorna, dá algum erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amigo, eu fiz uma que fazia algo parecido que funcionava da seguinte forma:

vc colocaria no caso o codigo direto no HTML, na view que teria o link para clicar no PDF

```
<strong>
   <a href="~/MediaFiles/Comuns/PDF/Arquivo Fatura.pdf" target="_blank">Visualizar PDF do manual</a>
</strong>
```

testei aqui no meu esta funcionando perfeitamente

Comment: Boa, deu certo, amigo! Muito obrigado!

Comment: fico feliz em ajudar :D